# Is there any example of open set $G$ such as $G \supset E$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove $E$ is measurable set. It's mean $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists G: \; G \supset E \; \left| G \setminus E \right|^{*} < \varepsilon$ where $E = \bigcup_{n=3}^{\infty}{[1+\frac{1}{n}, 2 - \frac{1}{n})}$ 
I have tried to find $G = [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}, something)$ such as $G \setminus E = [1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}, 1)$ but I couldn't find such set $G$

Can somebody hint me such $G$ or offer another set to prove $E$ is measurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $G=\cup_{n=3}^{\infty} (1+\frac  1 n -\frac 1 {n^{2}}, 2-\frac  1 n)$.